# Is it possible to make a layer consisting of several objects draggable in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I would like to make a group of objects simultaneously draggable, so that they can only be dragged together. That means: if I move one object, the other objects in the layer will be moved to.
In particular I have a geojson file with a featureCollection consisting of several objects and I want them to be draggable but behave as a single marker on the map.

So far I have:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView...
...

var drag = L.geoJson(null,{
    draggable: true,
});

omnivore.geojson('data.geojson', null, drag).addTo(mymap)
```

I have included  [Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag)  to make the geojson objects draggable.

In the result every feature in the geojson feature collection is draggable independently. How can I couple them?

Comment: Try looking in this, it might have a solution you are looking for. https://www.phpclasses.org/leafletmapportal

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it by having d3 handle the dragging part. Select the group element after it has been added to the map and use translate on it via d3.drag().

```
var d = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }];
d3.select('svg').select('g').data(d)
  .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  .call(onDragDrop(dragmove, dropHandler));

function onDragDrop(dragHandler, dropHandler) {
  var drag = d3.drag();

  drag.on("drag", dragHandler)
      .on("end", dropHandler);
  return drag;
}

function dropHandler(d) {
    alert('dropped');
}

function dragmove(d) {
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - what is exactly the d value here?